# Custom Collection view cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, uicollectionview

I am new to iOS development and I am developing a buy/sell application. I am trying to make a collection view where I don't hard set the size of the collection view cell. Instead it would depend on the user who post up something they are selling. I realized that by hard coding the size of the boxes, everything looks "boxy". Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you would like to adjust cell's frame dynamically?

Comment: You should check out UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate's methods.

Comment: @EricZhang yes precisely

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using the default flow layout, there are two options:

1. You can have self-sizing cells if you:

   - define unambiguous constraints between your cell and its subviews;
   - do not define fixed width/height constraints for the image view;
   - set the `estimatedItemSize` of your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

     ```
     let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
     layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
     ```

   Auto layout will then resize the image view to fit the image, and the cell will then resize itself to fit that, accordingly. So, for example, with some random image sizes, the standard flow layout will resize the cells automatically for us:

   [image: sample collection view]

   Now this is a simple cell with a randomly-sized, solid color image in an image view and constraints of `H:|[imageView]|` and `V:|[imageView]|`, but the same idea works with complicated cells, too. You just need to make sure that the top/bottom and leading/trailing constraints of the cells are unambiguous.

   Note, if you rely upon the implicit size of the image view, this assumes of course that the images are already sized consistently for the device. If not, you might want to create constraints for the image view height/width, include `@IBOutlet` references for that, and then set the `constant` for those constraints in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. But, to manage memory efficiently, you generally want to downsize the images to an appropriate size anyway, so this is generally not necessary.
2. Alternatively, you can specify a delegate (a [`UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout)) of the flow layout and then implement [`sizeForItemAt:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview).

Comment: thanks for the share, it really helped me get a grasp of the Collectionveiwlayout. So I want the width of the cell to stay the same but the height can be dynamically changed. Should I just set the width constraint for each box?

Comment: Yep, you can just set the width constraint. But, I wouldn't then rely upon auto layout combining this fixed with constraint plus calculating the height of the image view implicitly from the combination of not only the image dimensions, but also this fixed width constraint. (It actually does remarkably well, but it's not perfect.) So, if you're going to have a fixed width constraint, then I'd add an outlet to the height constraint and set it's `constant` accordingly. The trick there is that the dynamic height constraint should have a priority below 1000 (even 999 is sufficient).

Comment: The other alternative is lose the constraint-based cell height and fall back to [`sizeForItemAt:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview).

Comment: For the constraint-based solution, see https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/6357d2b985f93c76c2d85c662be5a06a